# Why isn't my removeString function removing the characters?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm working through an exercise in a book, I'm not allowed to use any library functions aside from `printf` and `scanf`.

I have written a program that takes in a string. You can then input how many characters you would then like to remove from the string. And then choose at which index, this is performed.

My attempt at this is to loop through the characters I want to keep at the end of my function and then replace them with the functions I want to lose.

For some reason it is doing the exact opposite.

If I input the string: `"the wrong son"`
and then choose to remove 6 characters and begin at the 4th index of the array,

I SHOULD get: `"the son"`

Instead, I am getting `"the wro"`.

I have been banging my head against this for 4 hours now.

Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removeString(char source[], int start, int count);
int stringLength(const char string[]);

    int main(void)
    {
        int start, count;
        char source[20]; 

        printf("What's your string?\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", source);

        printf("How many characters do you want to remove?\n");
        scanf("%i", &count);

        // Choose which index to start deletion from
        printf("Where are we starting from?\n");
        scanf("%i", &start);

        // Call function to remove characters from string
        removeString(source, start, count);

        // print out result, stored in source
        printf("Here's the result: %s\n", source);

        return 0;
    }

    void removeString(char source[], int start, int count)
    {
        int i, j;

        // Find length of string
        int length = stringLength(source);


        //loop through the last few characters that we DO want to keep until we hit the end of the string 
        for(i = (start+count); i <= length; i++)
        {
            //loop backwards through the string, from the first of the ones we want to keep, stop at the 'start' of the index
            for(j = (start+count)-1; j <= start; j--)
            {
                // assign 'i' which is the last few characters we want to keep and put them in the place of the characters we want to delete
                source[j] = source[i];
            }
        }

        // assign a null character to end the string once we've finished modifying
        source[count + 1] = '\0';
    }

    int stringLength(const char string[])
    {
        int count =0;

        while(string[count] != '\0')
            count++;

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `for(j = (start+count)-1; j <= start; j--)` have `j >= start` instead?

Comment: You don't need nested loops for this... just one loop, and two array indices.

Comment: if I switch out <= for >=, my output end up as just `the`

Comment: `"s"` not useful in `scanf("%[^\n]s", source);`

Comment: that's the reason it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

In your indexing.

Instead of posting a simple solution, I will try to make you understand where you went wrong.

```
for(i = (start+count); i <= length; i++)
```

Here, for the input 'the wrong son', `length` will be equal to 13. As a result you are indexing `source[13]`, which is *not* an out-of-bounds access, since you have statically initialize your array to 20 cells, but it's still exceeding the length of your input string by 1.

So change it to `i < length`.

---

Now this loop:

```
for(j = (start+count)-1; j <= start; j--)
```

it says start from 9 (for the example input) and decrease `j` until it's less or equal than 4, doesn't make sense, you meant to write:

`j >= start`

---

Now grab a piece of paper and write down your input and your pointers please:

```
start = 4
count = 6
length = 13

       start    start+count
         |           |
         V           V
|t|h|e| |w|r|o|n|g| |s|o|n|
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 101112
```

Run your algorithm now.

You are getting i-th character and overwrite the all j-th ones, that's why you end up with 'the nnn' after applying my fixes, right?

So what you want to do is to go until `start` plus what you have already overwritten and should *not* overwrite again!

As a result, change this:

`j >= start`

to

```
j >= start + i - (start + count);
```

and you should get this output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
What's your string?
the wrong son
How many characters do you want to remove?
6
Where are we starting from?
4
Here's the result: the son
```

If that's not the case, tell me to post the whole fixed code.

---

*Edit*:

> my appending of '\0' was wrong?

No, it's correct (after at least all the fixes proposed in this answer). Let's check with this code:

```
printf("source = %s\n", source);
printf("count = %d\n", count);
printf("source[count] = %c\n", source[count]);
printf("source[count + 1] = %c\n", source[count + 1]);
source[count + 1] = '\0';
```

which gives:

```
source = the sonnnnson
count = 6
source[count] = n
source[count + 1] = n
```

So `count + 1` is equal to 7, which is the second 'n' in the string, which is exactly where we want to place the null terminator.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand that. if j == 9, and start == 4, and I'm decrementing j each time, how will it ever get low enough? I was trying to work my way down through the index in order to change values

Comment: @MattCleary you want to start from 9 and go until 4, by decreasing 1 every time. So start from `start+count-1` and go all the way down to `start`. Do that until `j >= start`. So `j` starts with 9, then goes to 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 (which is still equal to `start = 4`) but then `j` goes to 3 and it's not greater or equal to `start` now, thus the loop stops, right? :)

Comment: Can you please explain why @ameyCU below said that my appending of '\0' was wrong? You didn't flag that as an error and it doesn't seem to have effected my code negatively at all

Comment: @MattCleary I am not sure why ameyCU pointed that, but notice that he didn't apply my fixes, so I will have to go through his answer to answer this (oh I could't resist, but still I do not know why he mentioned that). Check my update. BTW, nice question, +1.

Answer (score 3):

You only need one for loop to make this happen. Assuming we can successfully avoid running over the end of the string you could write something like this:

```
for(i = start; i < start + count && i < length; i++) {
   source[i] = source[i+count];
}
```

Then you'd just need to set a null character in the right position. But, that's not at count. Perhaps at length-count-1 (or consider start+count) because you're deleting "count" characters.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you.

Why didn't my code work before? What exactly did I do wrong in the loops? I have it over on paper and in the debugger with printf statements a thousand times. I still made sense to me, though I was obviously wrong.

Comment: This line isn't a good one: for(j = (start+count)-1; j <= start; j--), because j is never less than start in this scenario. Perhaps if you use >= start, although I haven't worked it all the way through for myself (and, fixing your null character set of course).

Comment: I tried using >= but that only outputted "the".

j = (start+count)-1 == 9 though. If j is decremented, then after 5 loops it will be equal to start, which is 4.

Comment: Your j loop needs to start at the end. length-1. So after it is decremented, it should end at the proper place that way. And you probably don't want to stop at start for it. You'll want to stop elsewhere. length-count-1 perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your loop -

```
for(i=start, j=(start+count) ; j<=length; i++, j++){
    source[i]=source[j];    
}
// assign a null character to end the string once we've finished modifying

source[strlen(source)-1]='\0';   // include string.h for strlen()
```

What this loop basically does is , initialize from `start` (`i`) position and it copies the values of index `start+count` (`j`) at index `i`. And at last append the `'\0'` to array.

Also regarding `source[count+1]='\0';` was incorrect as it would append it at wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using fgets to read input and sscanf to parse the integers. Check the return of sscanf (or scanf) to see if there were problems. In `removeString` a pair of pointers could be used to iterate through the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void removeString(char source[], int start, int count);
int stringLength(const char string[]);

int main(void)
{
    int start, count;
    int result = 0;
    char source[120];
    char input[120];

    printf("What's your string?\n");
    if ( ( fgets( source, sizeof ( source), stdin)) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not get input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    source[strcspn ( source, "\n")] = '\0';//remove newline

    do {
        printf("How many characters do you want to remove?\n");
        if ( ( fgets( input, sizeof ( input), stdin)) == NULL) {
            printf ( "could not get input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        result = sscanf(input, "%d", &count);
    } while ( result != 1);//loop on bad input

    do {
        printf("Where are we starting from?\n");
        if ( ( fgets( input, sizeof ( input), stdin)) == NULL) {
            printf ( "could not get input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        result = sscanf(input, "%d", &start);
    } while ( result != 1);//loop on bad input

    removeString(source, start, count);

    printf("Here's the result: %s\n", source);
    return 0;
}

void removeString(char source[], int start, int count)
{
    char *to = NULL, *from =NULL;

    int length = stringLength(source);

    if ( start > length) {//very short source
        return;
    }

    if ( start + count > length) {//source still too short
        source[start] = '\0';//truncate at start
        return;
    }
    to = &source[start];
    from = &source[start + count];

    while(*from)//loop until '\0'
    {
        *to = *from;
        to++;
        from++;
    }
    //set '\0'
    *to = *from;
}

int stringLength(const char string[])
{
    int count =0;
    while(string[count] != '\0')
        count++;
    return count;
}
```